# php ZipArchive addfile not work

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

Here's my code

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('memory_limit','1G');

$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open(__DIR__.'/xxx.zip') === TRUE) {
        echo __DIR__.'/CPInfo.txt'."\n";
        $zip->addFile(__DIR__.'/CPInfo.txt', 'newname.txt');        
        $x =  $zip->close();
        var_dump($x);
        echo 'ok';
} else {
        echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

I have run command

```
[root@localhost]# php test.php
```

And the output is

```
/data/yyy/CPInfo.txt
bool(true)
ok
```

No errors are given while adding the txt into the .zip.
When I open xxx.zip, nothing is changed.
File xxx.zip contains more than 1000 files and 100 folders

When i remove 900 files from xxx.zip and run this script again, it's work.

What am I doing wrong?

file open limit

```
ulimit -a
```

output

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 514831
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 99999
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 500000
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

php version

```
PHP 5.5.13 (cli) (built: Jun  3 2014 13:27:36) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: you want to add new files to zip folder?

Comment: yep, I want to add CPInfo.txt to xxx.zip

Comment: can you re check your ulimit.give it more than that files.

Comment: open files (-n) 99999 more than files in xxx.zip

Comment: give other zip file nam and try like yyy.zip?

Comment: and tel me xxx.zip file size

Comment: original: xxx.zip size is ~40MB, after remove 900 files is ~ 15MB

Comment: have you tried with yyy.zip file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74256/discussion-between-ninja-and-user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm downgrade from php55 to php54 and everything work well.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code this works fine.

**Code:-**

```
<?php

//After zip files are stored in this folder
$file= "/data/yyy/xxx.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive;
echo "zip started.\n";

if ($zip->open($file, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
        $zip->addFile("/data/yyy/CPInfo.txt");
        }
    $zip->close();
    echo 'done';
?>
```

I have tried with one file add to zip in xxx.zip file "CPInfo.txt", it's added successfully.

Hope this help